# How to test a versioned REST application with a vendor mime type?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a rest servlet using Jersey and I want to version it by using a vendor type. Here's the code:

```
@Path("/data")
public class UploadData {

    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @Consumes("application/vnd.blah.data-v1.0.0+xml")
    public void addCustomerData(String xml) {
        System.out.println("xml =  " + xml);
    }
}
```

I'm using a add-on to Chrome to test it (Simple Rest Client) but no matter what I do, I always get a "415 Unsupported Media Type" error returned.

Do I have to modify the headers of the client or is it something I can specify in the xml? I would like to still be able to use the Chrome add-on instead of a custom written client.

Comment: Can you see the HTTP headers being modified to `Content-type: application/vnd.blah.data-v1.0.0+xml` by your Chrome plugin? Did you test with `curl -H "Content-type: application/vnd.blah.data-v1.0.0+xml" -X POST -d 'your post data' your-url` ?

Comment: That was it. I just had to add a header in the client to have Content-type: application/vnd.blah.data-v1.0.0+xml

Comment: Yes, looks like you need to modify the headers in the Simple Rest Client. The [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US) may be better suited for its superior UI. I only mention this because I have successfully used it on many projects for quickly testing RESTful interfaces.